# calculate months between two dates in java

Tags: java

i need to calculate months between two dates, 
if the startDate=2013.01.01, endDate=2013.01.31 the answer should be 1, 
startDate=2013.01.01, endDate=2013.02.01 the answer should be 2.
please help

Comment: i just want to do a calculation by getting the months. i wants to get the number of months.if the start date=january 1st and the end date=feb 1st there have the january and febrary like wise i wants to know how many months are there in between that two dates

Answer (score 8):

Use Joda [Months](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Months.html):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate.getTime());
DateTime end= new DateTime(endDate.getTime());
int months = Months.monthBetween(start, end).getMonths();
```

Comment: Good way in 2013. Today prefer `java.time` instead.