# How to get right number of months and day between several dates?

Tags: java, date

I need to compute the proper number of months and days between a list of intervals:

```
31/03/2017  30/09/2017
01/10/2017  31/03/2018
01/04/2018  30/09/2018
01/10/2018  31/12/2019
```

If I compute all days between these intervals and then divide by 30, I got

```
MONTHS: 33 DAYS: 12
```

but what I want is:

```
MONTHS: 33 DAYS: 1 (the only day to compute is the first day of first interval)
```

Comment: can you show us some code please

Comment: I don't think it is a right approach to divide the days by 30 as some months can be 30 or 31 or 28/29. It doesn't provide the accurate result. You may need to define the requirement correctly as the above example showing the end and start date of the month.

Comment: Use the the java time package probably

Comment: Or use the Joda package if you're pre-Java 8: https://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: @MichaelMurray Or on Java 6 or 7 even better, use the backport of java.time: [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: Are you counting all the months and days from the first to the last date? So we can safely ignore all those coming in between? That’s the only way I can get 33 months.

Comment: @OleV.V. if someone is dealing with time and is below java 8, it is recommended to update to 8 or above because below 8 is just a mess when it comes to time. Additionally, it is much slower.

Comment: `Period.between(LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 31), LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 31).plusDays(1))` yields `P2Y9M1D`. Read as a period of 2 years 9 months 1 day (2 years 9 months equals 33 months). The `.plusDays(1)` is to make sure both start and end dates are included.

Comment: [3 ways to get number of months and year between two dates in Java?](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-get-number-of-months-and-years-between-two-dates-in-java.html) Please search for more.

Comment: Possible (near?) duplicate of [Java 8 calculate months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950145/java-8-calculate-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder No, there is need to force an update to Java 8. Most of the *java.time* functionality defined in JSR 310 is available in the project mentioned by Ole V.V., [*ThreeTen-BackPort*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Both *java.time* and the back-port were led by the same man, Stephen Coleburne. He also led the *Joda-Time* project which is now in maintenance-mode, with migration to *java.time* recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386702/642706) is correct, and wisely uses the modern *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDateRange`

As a bonus, I will mention adding the excellent [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class. This class represents a span of time as a pair of `LocalDate` objects. That seems a match to your business problem.

```
LocalDate start = … ;
LocalDate stop = … ;
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
```

From this `LocalDateRange` object you can obtain the `Period` objects used in that [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386702/642706)

```
Period period = range.toPeriod() ;
```

Notice that `LocalDateRange` has handy methods for comparison, such as `abuts`, `contains`, `overlaps`, and so on.

## Half-Open

You may be confused about how to handle end-of-month/first-of-month.

Generally in date-time handling, it is best to represent a span-of-time using the Half-Open approach. In this approach, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So a month starts on the first of the month and runs up to, but does *not* include the first of the next month.

```
LocalDateRange rangeOfMonthOfNovember2019 = 
    LocalDateRange.of(
        LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.NOVEMBER , 1 ) ,
        LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.DECEMBER , 1
    )
;
```

You can ask each `LocalDateRange` for days elapsed: [`LocalDateRange::lengthInDays`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#lengthInDays()).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
List < LocalDateRange > ranges = new ArrayList <>( 4 );
ranges.add(
        LocalDateRange.of(
                LocalDate.parse( "31/03/2017" , f ) ,
                LocalDate.parse( "30/09/2017" , f )
        )
);
ranges.add(
        LocalDateRange.of(
                LocalDate.parse( "01/10/2017" , f ) ,
                LocalDate.parse( "31/03/2018" , f )
        )
);
ranges.add(
        LocalDateRange.of(
                LocalDate.parse( "01/04/2018" , f ) ,
                LocalDate.parse( "30/09/2018" , f )
        )
);
ranges.add(
        LocalDateRange.of(
                LocalDate.parse( "01/10/2018" , f ) ,
                LocalDate.parse( "31/12/2019" , f )
        )
);

// Sum the periods, one from each range.
Period period = Period.ZERO;
int days = 0;
for ( LocalDateRange range : ranges )
{
    days = ( days + range.lengthInDays() );
    period = period.plus( range.toPeriod() ).normalized();
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "ranges: " + ranges );
System.out.println( "days: " + days + "  |  pseudo-months: " + ( days / 30 ) + " and days: " + ( days % 30 ) );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
```

> ranges: [2017-03-31/2017-09-30, 2017-10-01/2018-03-31, 2018-04-01/2018-09-30, 2018-10-01/2019-12-31]
>
> days: 1002  |  pseudo-months: 33 and days: 12
>
> period: P2Y5M119D

If you insist on fully-closed rather than half-open, `LocalDateRange` can still help you with its [`ofClosed`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#ofClosed(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)) method. But I strongly suggest you adopt half-open instead, as I believe you will find it makes your life easier to use one consistent approach across all your code. And educate your users. I have seen much confusion among office staff making incorrect assumptions about inclusive/exclusive dates. Your practice of tracking end-of-month to end-of-month seems likely to engender ever more confusion.

## `YearMonth`

Another class you might find useful is built into Java: [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html). This class represents a particular month as a whole unit.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2019 , Month.NOVEMBER ) ;
```

Notice methods such as `atDay` to produce a `LocalDate` from a `YearMonth`.

## ISO 8601

Tip: Make a habit of using only the ISO 8601 standard formats rather than localized formats when serializing date-time values as text.

So for a date, use YYYY-MM-DD.

The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" )
```

The standard ISO 8601 format for an entire month is YYYY-MM such as `2019-11`.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse( "2019-11" ) ;  // Entire month of November 2019.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: You fail to mention periods as a valid and simple/useful method for each only specifies intervals. Therefore, I will be marking this answer as incorrect until further revision.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder Actually, upon further reflection, I now see that `Period` is *not* the solution here. The Question asks for pseudo-months as arbitrary 30-day chunks of time, unrelated to calendar. The `Period` class separates years-months from days. See the output of my example code: P2Y5M119D.

Comment: BasilBourque fair

Answer (score 1):

You may ignore the dates in between and just calculate the difference between the first and the last date:

```
    LocalDate first = LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 31);
    LocalDate lastInclusive = LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 31);
    LocalDate lastExclusive = lastInclusive.plusDays(1);
    Period between = Period.between(first, lastExclusive);

    System.out.format("Months: %s days: %d%n",
            between.toTotalMonths(), between.getDays());
```

Output is in this case:

> Months: 33 days: 1

Since `Period.between()` calculates the difference up to the end date *exclusive* and you want the end date included, I add one day to your end date.

Months can be 28, 29, 30 and 31 days long and are longer than 30 days on the average, which is why dividing by 30 gave you too many days. You may read up on the exact working of `Period.between()` and check if it always gives you what you want.

**Links**

- Oracle Turorial: [section *Period and Duration*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)
- [Documentation of `Period.bewteen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-)