# How can I calculate the difference between two dates(confirming some logic)?

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

In a tutorial I am watching,I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates. I need the initMonth and the finishMonth with the idea being to subtract the initMonth from the finishMonth and calculate the difference.

I can do something like this using the Calendar class(and then something similar with the finishMonth):

```
int initMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

...but the problem is that if the initMonth is May(for example) and the endMonth is January; when I subtract the endMonth from the initMonth I will get 1-5=-4--and I will have a negative difference. In order to solve this problem, the instructor came with the solution of multiplying the YEAR * 12 and then adding the month like this:

```
int initMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) *12 + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

However, this doesn't make any sense to me since the year will return something like 2021 * 12 + month to some extremely large number. My guess was that he meant MONTH so then we will get the months in the year plus the month. Would I be correct? I'm unsure, and wanted to confirm this logic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to use the java.time API instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950145/java-8-calculate-months-between-two-dates

Comment: Instructors suggesting to use `Calendar` in 2021 deserve to be sacked. That class is *so* poorly designed and *so* outdated.

Comment: Under the linked original question look into [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42895017/5772882) and [the one by Roland Tepp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811261/5772882) using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If I understand correctly these match your requirement better than [the one by Kuchi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147750/5772882) also using java.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tutorial is obsolete by several years. Never use `Calendar` or `Date` class. Use only *java.time* classes.

Apparently you want to calculate elapsed months.

```
LocalDate then = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
Period elapsed = Period.between ( then , today ) ;
int months = elapsed.toMonths() ;
```

Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This has been covered many times already.

Comment: If you think that "this has been covered many times already", shouldn't you mark this question as a duplicate instead of answering it? (Especially as an experienced SO user as you are with 217k rep?)